# VS Code + Arduino IDE: How to select which sketch will compile? Missing something obvious here

Tags: visual-studio-code, arduino

Long-time Arduino IDE user, one-day VS Code + Arduino extension user:

When I first load a sketch and do "Arduino:Initialize", the name of the sketch is stored in the arduino.json settings file, e.g. "sketch": "esp32_test/esp32_test.ino". It then compiles ok when I press the "Verify" button.

But if I close that sketch and open a different one, and then do "Arduino:Initialize", the first file is NOT replaced in the arduino.json file. The first one remains there. I get a message that says, "Arduinio.json is already generated." So when I try to compile the new file, the old one is compiled instead.

The only way I've been able to compile a different file is to manually edit the arduino.json settings file to remove the "sketch": "esp32_test/esp32_test.ino" entry. Then AND ONLY THEN will the .json file update to allow me to compile the new file.

Shouldn't this happen automatically when I select/edit a file and hit the Verify button? Maybe there's an issue with my installation...?

(forgot to mention: VS Code + Arduino on OSX 10.14.6)

Comment: I think from reading https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-arduino that you can only have one main sketch in each VS Code workspace.  If you want to compile two different sketches you need to make two different VS code workspaces.

Comment: OK...but if I close the first one completely, then close and restart VSCode, and then open another sketch, the first closed sketch is still the one that compiles, not the open sketch. There is only one sketch open.

Comment: Oh wait...are you saying that the first file opened in a workspace remains the file that is ALWAYS compiled for that workspace...and then, if I want to compile a different file, I have to close that workspace and open a different workspace? I can't just close the first file and open a second file and compile that one? That's quite different than the Arduino IDE....

Comment: I haven't done it, but that's the way the documentation reads.  A workspace can have multiple sketches but there is the main sketch and all the other ones are called by that main one.  So for each separate program (main sketch) it reads like you need a different workspace for each.

Comment: Hopefully someone who has actually done it comes along and answers.

Comment: Well, I just did a full workspace dump and restart. No luck. For some reason, the arduino.json file still holds the very first sketch I chose previously. The only luck I'm having at compiling a different file is deleting the "sketch:" entry in arduino.json. This can't be right....? A couple of others had this problem a while back on the Arduino forum but nobody gave an answer...except somebody called it a dumb question...sigh...

Answer (score 5):

Down at the bottom, on the right you'll see the Arduino status bar.  There you'll find your board, your programmer, your port... and the .ino file that you're compiling.  Click there, change the name to the sketch you want to compile and done!

Comment: Thanks! Will try it first thing in the morning...sorry for the delayed response, we were evacuated during the fires and just got power and internet back...trying to get back to a normal computer-driven lifestyle again... ;)

Comment: Hmmm....on the bottom right Arduino status bar, I have C++ config, serial port, serial monitor, board config, programmer, language mode, and editor configurations...BUT NO file name, no ".ino" file to change, as you mentioned in your answer...any ideas?

Comment: OK, so regarding the no file name on status bar issue...if I open one of the Arduino example files at the bottom of the left-side pane, a new standalone window is opened with the .ino file in it, and at the bottom of this window is the name of the .ino file, unlike the main window, as described above. I can change the name of this .ino file, but the new file isn't compiled, the original example file is still compiled. The VSCode environment has me baffled so far...

Answer (score 3):

I know exactly the issue you are having - because it happens to me quite often.

In the status bar, often the sketch file name **will not** be displayed for some reason - I think this is an issue with the Arduino extension.  You'll see everything else you need - board, port, etc, but not the "target sketch"

Here is how you can change the "target sketch":

1. Open the command pallete (Ctrl + Shift + P for PC - CMD + Shift + P for mac)
2. Type in "sketch"
3. Select the option "Arduino: Select Sketch"
4. Select the sketch you want to upload/verify -> this will now become the active sketch

Like other respondents mentioned, it "should" be shown in the task bar, but for some reason it does not sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

It's no intuitive.
You should select the sketch in the status bar:
[image]

and then you can change the sketch in the upper screen text box:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the arduino.json file in the .vscode directory is not set up correctly, the target sketch will not appear at the lower panel. Correct syntax of the file will imply that the target sketch is displayed at the lower panel. Otherwice the file name is not shown. Clicking on the target skecth file name will cause the list of alternative target sketches  will be listed at the top of the VIsual Code window. From this list, you can choose another target sketch to be compiled.